# ASP.NET Textbox value coming empty on server side when set from JQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I am setting asp.net textbox's value from javascript and then trying to access the same from code behind, but its coming empty. I am totally clueless why it is happening that way.

As suggested somewhere, I tried to change ASP.NET textbox control to input HTML control with runat server, things worked like a charm. But I am desperate to know why the hell asp.net textbox behave that way.

Below are the code blocks:

**MarkUP**:

```
<div class="ingredient-block">
    <span>
       <asp:Localize ID="lblIngrQty" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources, lblIngrQty %>"></asp:Localize></span><br>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" CssClass="txtBack" Width="50px" runat="server" TabIndex="10" onchange="fnVerifyQuantityValue(this);" onfocus="fnShowQtyOnFocus(this);" onblur="fnHideKeywordWindow(this);"></asp:TextBox>
       <actAjax:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TeterxtBox5_TextBoxWamarkExtender" runat="server"
       WatermarkText="<%$ Resources:Resources, lblIngrQty %>" Enabled="True" WatermarkCssClass="watermark1" TargetControlID="txtQty">
       </actAjax:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function fnShowQtyOnFocus(oQty) {
        var hiddenQtyKw = fnUnEscapeXMLValue($("#<%=hdnQtyCommonKw.ClientID%>").val());

        if (hiddenQtyKw.length > 1) {
            var xmlCommonQty = $.parseXML(hiddenQtyKw);
            $XMLCommonQTY = $(xmlCommonQty);
            var keywordCollection = $XMLCommonQTY.find('Name');

            var ul = document.createElement("ul");

            for (index = 0; index < keywordCollection.length; index++) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = keywordCollection[index].textContent;

                li.onclick = function () {
                    if ($("#" + oQty.id).val() == "Qty" || $("#" + oQty.id).val() == "Mängd") {
                        $("#" + oQty.id).val("");
                        $("#" + oQty.id).val(this.innerHTML);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#" + oQty.id).val($("#" + oQty.id).val() + this.innerHTML);
                    }
                };

                $(ul).append(li);
            }

            $(".showKeyword").html("");
            $(".showKeyword").show();
            $(".showKeyword").append(ul);

            var offset = $("#" + oQty.id).offset();
            var posY = offset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
            var posX = offset.left - $(window).scrollLeft();

            $(".showKeyword").css("top", posY - 20);
            $(".showKeyword").css("left", posX);
        }
    }
```

Don't wonder about the JS function. It is creating an unordered list with suppose 5 li elements, adding that ul element to a div and showing the div above the txtQty control. Then user will click on any of the 5 elements and then I copy the li value to txtQty control. See the onclick handler.

So, now when I go to server by a button postback, I don't see any value in txtQty.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my finding, the issue was coming because I was using AJAX watermark control that extends this textbox. When I removed it, it worked.

So, my solution is to use input with runat server. And for watermarking use placeHolder attribute.